# Activating or Selecting a worksheet dynamically

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm dynamically creating a excel file using vbs and ExcelXML in javascript. Something like this.

```
acdbCon.OpenConnection();
rs = acdbCon.GetRecordSet(GetQryABC(a,b,c));
workbookObj = new WorkbookXML("abc");
xmlBody.append(workbookObj.AddWorkbook().join(""));
xmlBody.append(workbookObj.AddStyleSheet().join(""));
abcObj = new abcXML(xmlBody, rs, PAGE_HEADER, PAGE_SUB_HEADER,.,.,.);
xmlBody = abcObj .AddSheet(1, "sheet1");
xmlBody = abcObj .AddBlankSheet(2, "sheet2");
xmlBody = abcObj .AddSheet(3, "sheet3");

xmlBody.append(workbookObj.EndWorkbook());
acdbCon.CloseConnection();
var fileNameDate = new Date();
var fileName=tpInfo.GetDLN() + "_ABC_" + (fileNameDate.getMonth()+1) + "_" + fileNameDate.getDate() + "_" + fileNameDate.getYear();
var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\doc\\" + fileName + ".xls", true);
document.getElementById("export_msg").innerHTML="File Exported to:   c:\\doc\\" + fileName + ".xls";
fh.WriteLine(xmlBody.toString()); 
fh.Close();
var objExcel;
objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
objExcel.Workbooks.Open('c:\\doc\\' + fileName + '.xls',false,false);
var wkSh = objExcel.Workbooks(fileName + '.xls').Worksheets("Sheet1");
var rcWkSh = objExcel.Workbooks(fileName + '.xls').Worksheets("Sheet2");
var rcWkSh2 = objExcel.Workbooks(fileName + '.xls').Worksheets("Sheet3");
```

Once the excel is created and saved it is opened for viewing. My requirement is to dynamically activate/select/show any sheet of my choice when the sheet is opened. Like suppose the user wants to have sheet3 active and selected when the workbook is opened.

I tried the following
    objExcel.Workbooks(fileName + '.xls').sheets(1).activate;
    objExcel.Workbooks(fileName + '.xls').sheets(1).select();
    objExcel.Workbooks(fileName + '.xls').sheets(1).Activate;
    objExcel.Workbooks(fileName + '.xls').Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate;
but nothing worked. Any idea on how I can achieve this. Thanks.

Ravi

Comment: No, how do you call it? like this <br/>
objExcel.Workbooks(fileName + '.xls').sheets(1).view;

Answer (score 1):

Use the Excel Macro recorder and perform the operation you'd like to perform in the automation script then copy the code the recorder generates and use it in your script.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
```